# Changing the default resolution with a virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, knoppix

I'm using VMware on windows to run Knoppix but the default resolution is too small and changing the resolution each time I load it with `su xrandr` is annoying.

Is there a way to change the default resolution permanently?

Answer (score 1):

You could try altering it (Knoppix) and then remaster it in order to save the current configuration permanently.

http://knoppix.net/wiki3/index.php?title=Knoppix_Remastering_Howto

You could also try using a 'saveconfig' script. Not 100% sure but it would make sense that this would be one setting it would save.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/remaster-knoppix-without-remastering

There's also save config capabilities in later versions of Knoppix aren't there which should handle this type of thing?

Another would be install to a virtual disk and use the relevant cheat code to change the resolution.

> knoppix screen=1280x1024            Use specified Screen resolution for X

http://knoppix.net/wiki3/index.php?title=Cheat_Codes

Comment: By virtual disk you mean a virtual machine or dual boot?